# Should this outlier in this linear regression model be excluded?

Tags: regression

If fit into a simple linear regression model both with and without this point, which of the two lines would be preferable in this case?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the true relationship is a straight line over the entire region?

Comment: Would the straight line on the Excluded line be considered extrapolating the data then?

Comment: Looking at your $x$-axis, I see that the measurement is arm length. The "outlier" point has an arm length less than $0$. Something went wrong. Perhaps the person doing data entry made a typo. I might consider discarding that point, but only after I try to salvage it (checking nearby keys to figure out what the number is supposed to be, for instance). I am interested in how you respond to what seems to be a physical impossibility present in your data.

Comment: Is this a real dataset you're analysing? What's the story behind the negative value of "arm length" of the outlier?

Comment: Please include confidence, or better prediction, bands with both regression lines so you can see how useful or useless the regression is for your purposes. Also attach a file with the data so others can do alternative analyses.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the answer depends on the meaning of the data and the aim of analysis. Surely this outlier has a huge influence on the regression line, and this is a worry for the interpretation of the regression result. If you can go back and find out that something went wrong with this observation, it should be excluded.

In this example it looks like the outlier refers to a negative arm length, and this is impossible, so the observation looks erroneous and should therefore be excluded (or, if possible, corrected).

In a general situation, however, outliers may be valid observations, or it may not be possible to find out whether they are erroneous or not. In such a case removing the outlier is not normally recommended. There are robust regression methods that are less sensitive against outliers (and will here probably give you something that looks pretty much like the blue line). However, it may also be the case that any regression line is not valid over the whole possible range of x-values and the outlier may indicate that points with low x and points close to the non-outliers should not be fitted by the same line.

On the other hand, due to large variation in y-direction, low variation in x-direction, and small sample size, the blue line may not be very reliable and the red line may still be OK also for the non-ouliers, and the outlier may be quite valuable for the fit (were it not for the negative arm length). But one can hardly say that any of the two lines is "better". It needs to be accepted that the small data set only gives limited information, particularly there is not enough data to see whether a linear model that fits all observations together makes sense, or whether rather the non-outliers should be fitted without impact of the outlier.